# Seam PDF - Aligning "p:data" keys to the left

Tags: pdf, seam

I have the following code to generate a pdf from data:

```xml
<p:barchart is3D="true" legend="false" orientation="horizontal" width="520">    
    <p:series key="Gráfico">
        <ui:repeat var="ocr" value="#{myBean.value}" >
            <p:data key="#{ocr[0]}" value="#{ocr[1]}" />
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:series>
</p:barchart>
```

The problem is that the **key** from **p:data** gets aligned to the right (for some odd reason). I tried placing the code between divs with text-align, but it didn't worked.

I want the alignment to be on the left.

If someone has an answer, or at least an idea for me to try, I'd really appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is the value you're assigning an int or other numeric value? Trying casting it to a String instead.

Comment: My question is regarding style, because on the pdf the value gets aligned to the right. The code itself works perfectly.

Comment: I understand - I suggested it because the standard alignment for a numerical value may be right-align, as it is in other display formats. Strings are usually left-align. This might be a red herring, but it can't hurt to check